# Connect XML data

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to embed docusign on my website by using powerform. As of now I am using demo account and I am stuck with using DocuSign connect how would I create a sample connector and fetch XML data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please share with us what you tried so far.

Comment: @Aditi we have embedded docusign using powerform by using demo account within iframe. Now  I am working on how to configure docusign connect. Which URL i need to mention for publishing in demo account and how docusign is connected with powerform. Do we get any data or event notifications of every signers in connect

Comment: @Tamas rev I have just used html code to embed docusign on my web app and after finish signing its returning to parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't contact DocuSign connect, it contacts you! (Your application.)

1. Use the Administration tool--in the Connect section you can add a subscription to Connect, including your application's url.
2. When an event that you're interested in occurs (eg Envelope.Complete), Connect will make a POST HTTPS request to your application. The body of the post will be the XML notification message with the details on the envelope that had reached the complete (signed) state.

Ask additional questions on StackOverflow if you have additional questions.

Note: your server (your *listener*) must be on the public internet so it can be contacted by DocuSign.